# How can I see data of an api in SQL Server with a query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an [API](http://203.115.101.54/mobileapp/vehilestatus_snowman.php?veh_reg=all) - how can I see the data of this api in SQL Server? Please help. I am not aware how to open api data in SQL Server - I'm new to this. Just want to see the Select data inside this api.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this directly. 
I did two modification to api document you shared.

1. Convert it to a JSON file (.json format).
2. Removed `{"vehicleStatuslist":` and it's end bracket

You can view/download the file from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g9ygjnl2do9ipt3/api.json?dl=0).

```
    Declare @JSON varchar(max)

    SELECT @JSON = BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'E:\api.JSON', SINGLE_CLOB) as j

    SELECT * FROM OPENJSON (@JSON) 
       WITH(Veh_reg VARCHAR(MAX),[datetime] DATETIME,Ignition VARCHAR(MAX),Latitude 
              VARCHAR(MAX),Longitude VARCHAR(MAX),Speed VARCHAR(MAX)) as Results
```

I get the result as below.

[image]